# DIV stick to top till pushed offscreen by next DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a similar effect to the Instagram timeline on a project I am doing. My HTML is:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="title">
         <h1>Some title</h1>
 <span>Time here</span>

    </div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Which is repeated many times down the page, and my CSS is:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.item {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
.item h1, span{
    padding: 2px 0 5px 5px;
}
.item span{
    display: inline;
}
.title {
    background-color: blue;
}
.content {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

What I want to happen is when a user scrolls, `<div class="title">` sticks to the top when a user is scrolling, but when the next `<div class="title">` comes up it 'pushes' the previous one off screen and then fixes it's self to the top.

Screenshots:
[Picture 1](https://www.icloud.com/photostream/#AJGWZuqDJ0VAf;83FA1FAF-EE34-4035-B5A9-0F18B24B7938) - Look at the two headers, one for withhearts the other for brenton_clarke.
[Picture 2](https://www.icloud.com/photostream/#AJGWZuqDJ0VAf;18032AD1-8A3E-4E8F-A7EC-6EC28B58DF57) - brenton_clarke's header has reached the bottom of withheart's
[Picture 3](https://www.icloud.com/photostream/#AJGWZuqDJ0VAf;67EF94E9-0BB5-4172-96F3-807C78CDBBFB) - brenton_clarke's header is pushing withheart's offscreen
[Picture 4](https://www.icloud.com/photostream/#AJGWZuqDJ0VAf;768367FA-0937-4B6A-B582-EED4F7398CE2) - brenton_clarke's headers is now stuck to the top till pauloctavious pushes it off

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reb6X/)

Can anyone give me some help with this?

---

With the link suggested below I was able to get it sort-of working, but not great: http://jsfiddle.net/reb6X/1/

---

Having modified the jQuery to use .html() rather than .text() it works not to badly now: http://jsfiddle.net/reb6X/2/

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check out this jsfiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/kennis/JTvFZ/

I think it could get you in the right direction.

```
// Index of the currently 'active' section
var activeCache = null;

// Actual rendered height of a header element
var cloneHeight = function(){
    var $clone = $('<div class="clone"></div>').appendTo('body'),
        cloneHeight = $clone.outerHeight();
    $clone.remove();
    return cloneHeight;
}();

// Top offsets of each header
var offsets = [];

// Figure out which section is 'active'
var activeHeaderIndex = function(){
    var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
    for ( var i = 0; i < offsets.length; i++ )
        if ( offsets[i] - cloneHeight > scrollTop )
            return Math.max( i - 1, 0 );
}

// Build the 'offsets' array
$('.header').each(function(i, obj){
    offsets.push( $(this).offset().top );
});

// Listen to scroll events
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var active = activeHeaderIndex(), 
        scroll = document.body.scrollTop,
        clone = $('.clone').length,
        $active = $('.header').eq(active),
        prevTitle = $('.header').eq(active - 1).text(),
        title = $active.text(),
        $fixed = $('.fixed');
    // Hide fixed header
    if ( offsets[active] > scroll ){
        if ( !clone ){
            $('.header').eq(0).hide();
            $('<li class="clone">' + prevTitle + '</li>').insertBefore($active);
        }
        $fixed.hide();
    // Show fixed header
    } else {
        if ( clone ){
            $('.header').eq(0).show();
            $('.clone').remove();
        }
        $fixed.show();
    }
    // If we're not changing headers, exit
    if ( active == activeCache ) return;
    // Update active index
    activeCache = active;
    // Remove old fixed header (if any)
    $('.fixed').remove();
    // Add a new fixed header
    $fixed = $('<div class="fixed">' + title + '</div>').appendTo('body');
}).trigger('scroll');
```